# How do I configure the Windows 7 slide show delay?

Tags: windows-7, slideshow, delay

How do I configure the Windows 7 slide show delay?

I'd like to set the delay to either wait until I click the mouse to go to next item or set the delay time in seconds much higher than the default, but I can't find anyplace to set this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'd like to set the delay to either wait until I click the mouse to go to next item

For this purpose, you can just pause the slideshow by right clicking on the slideshow screen. After that, the picture will only change when you press the mouse button or arrow keys.

Comment: Pressing the space bar will also halt/resume the slideshow ... assuming you are talking about the slideshow feature available in Windows Explorer and NOT the ability to have the desktop background change periodically in a slideshow fashion.